# Unity 2D project structure: How to create Player dynamically based on script

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, structure

I need a little help for my inheritance of my player in my little 2D Game.
In fact, I don't know how I can create a new player, and add it to a list.

This is my project structure :
[image]

As you can see, in my scripts, I have a GameBase script, and PlayerBase script with PlayerLife, PlayerController and PlayerAimManager as child of PlayerBase.

In my prefabs, I have my camera with GameBase script, and PlayerPrefab, with player scripts.

My PlayerBase is a script witch define a player, like his life, speed, color etc... :

```
public class PlayerBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    protected float Life { get; set; }
    public  Color Color { get; set; }
    protected WeaponBase PrimaryWeapon { get; set; }
    protected WeaponBase SecondaryWeapon { get; set; }
    protected WeaponBase SelectedWeapon { get; set; }
    protected ScoreBase Score { get; set; }
    protected bool IsDead { get; set; }
    protected float Speed { get; set; }
    protected float JumpForce { get; set; }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        IsDead = false;

        //Reset rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

        Life = 100;
        Speed = 20;
        JumpForce = 4000;

        PrimaryWeapon = gameObject.AddComponent<SMG>();
        SecondaryWeapon = gameObject.AddComponent<Shotgun>();

        SelectedWeapon = PrimaryWeapon;
    }
}
```

(And my child works like this :)

```
public class PlayerLife : PlayerBase
{   
    // Use this for initialization
    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        var color = base.Color();
    }
}
```

Ok, now this is my problem :

How can I instantiate a new player and save it in list.

In my GameBase I do something like this:

```
public class GameBase : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public List<PlayerBase> Players { get; set; } 

    void Start()
    {
        var playerObj1 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Players/PlayerPrefab")) as GameObject;
        PlayerBase player1 = playerObj1.GetComponent<PlayerBase>();
        player1.Color = Color.red;
        player1.Name = "Naografix Red"; 

        var playerObj2 = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Players/PlayerPrefab")) as GameObject;
        PlayerBase player2 = playerObj2.GetComponent<PlayerBase>();
        player2.Color = Color.blue;
        player2.Name = "Foo Blue"; 

        Players = new List<PlayerBase>{
            player1,
            player2
        }
    }
}
```

If I do this, my color in my child player scripts don't have my color because is not static. But if I put Color to static prop, I can't change my color in my GameBase.

Well, I don't know if my inheritance is good or not.

I just want to create a player dynamically with child script based on PlayerBase to get his own variable.

**EDIT**

In fact, I don't know how I can create dynamically a player with custom properties.
I want to do this :

```
PlayerBase player1 = new PlayerBase();
player1.Name = "Nao";
player.Color = Color.Red;
```

And store it in my PlayerList. But I can't do this, because, no prefab is created.

So I instantiate a new GameObject with my PlayerPrefab.
-Ok, cool, my player is spawned, I'm going to apply some properties. Huh? How can I get my PlayerBase script?

Then, I get my PlayerBase with GetComponent, but still not working because I got my child (I don't have PlayerBase on my PlayerPrefab).
And if I put PlayerBase on it, every child have a different instance of my PlayerBase.

To conclude : How can I create a new Player based on PlayerBase, share all properties to my childs and spawn a PlayerPrefab with their properties ?

**ENDEDIT**

**EDIT With simple example**

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<PlayerBase> _players;
    public GameObject Player; 

    void Start () {
        _players = new List<PlayerBase>();

        var obj = Instantiate(Player);
        var playerBase = obj.GetComponent<PlayerBase>();
        playerBase.Color = Color.blue;
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}


public class PlayerBase : MonoBehaviour {

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    // Use this for initialization
    protected virtual void Start () {
         gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    protected virtual void Update () {

    }
}


public class PlayerLife : PlayerBase {

    // Use this for initialization
    protected override void Start () {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

My playerLife color is null. This is my first problem.

[image]

**ENDEDIT**

Ask me if you want more details.

Thanks

Comment: That naming though...Color Color, you may want to change that. It might even the reason why it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a public member (not a property) in a MonoBehaviour, the value set by the inspector is automatically serialized for that game object. So that when you instantiate from that game object it will be automatically restored into the instantiated game object.

*This also can be done without `public` accessor and with `[SerializeField]` attribute.*

Make sure that only your `PlayerLife` script inherits from `PlayerBase`. The rest of your scripts(PlayerController and PlayerAimManager) should inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

As, for your color problem, it is not showing because when you do `player2.Color = Color.blue;`, you modifying a `struct` which is a copy not a reference. You have to manually assign that color to  `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor`.

Your new PlayerBase script:

```
public class PlayerBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color Color;

    public Color matColor
    {
        get
        {
            Color = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetColor("_Color");
            return Color;
        }
        set
        {
            Color = value;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color);
        }
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        matColor = Color;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected virtual void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

PlayerLife:

```
public class PlayerLife : PlayerBase
{
    public PlayerBase pBase;

    void Awake()
    {
        pBase = this;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    protected override void Start()
    {
        matColor = Color;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected override void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

To use it from your game scriot:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<PlayerLife> _players;
    public GameObject Player;

    void Start()
    {
        _players = new List<PlayerLife>();

        GameObject obj = Instantiate(Player);
        PlayerLife playerLife = obj.GetComponent<PlayerLife>();
        playerLife.matColor = Color.blue;
        _players.Add(playerLife);

        GameObject obj2 = Instantiate(Player) as GameObject;
        PlayerLife playerLife2 = obj2.GetComponent<PlayerLife>();
        playerLife2.Color = Color.red;
        _players.Add(playerLife2);
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, if you decide to access `PlayerBase` from your `PlayerController` and `PlayerAimManager` script,

```
PlayerBase playerBase = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerBase>();
```

OR

```
PlayerBase playerBase = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerLife>().pBase;
```

Comment: I don't know what OP meant by "My color is null". Maybe he's that it doesn't appear in the Editor? If that's it then you are correct about "set{}get{}" property which is why it ain't showing in the Editor

Comment: @Programmer correct I emphasized the not-property thing, however I think OP does not know about field serialization since it automatically can be handled.

Comment: @Naografix you mean like adding a static array holding all the required colors?

Comment: No no, just a Color property, players have differents color. Like Life, Speed etc.
Look my simple example. As you can see, my top cube is black. However my base.Color is set, but not in my PlayerLife

Comment: You can download my simple example here : https://www.sendspace.com/file/55pbwa
I just want to create player with different color.

Comment: Ok. you want both. Life set automatically and players set dynamically. look at my edited answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131591/discussion-between-naografix-and-bijan).

Comment: Not working if I use two players or three. Every players have the same color